# "to the north of London", "north of London", or "in the north of London"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Consider these sentences:

> 1. The company's office is to the north of London.
> 2. The company's office is in the north of London.
> 3. The company's office is north of London.

As far as Grammar is concerned, I think all of them are valid. To show this, I just quote from the dictionaries:

- *"The Yorkshire Dales are twenty miles to the north of the city."*
- *"there will be heavy wintry showers, particularly in the north."*
- *"the town is twenty-five miles north of Newport."*

Would you please tell me what is the difference between these sentences?

Comment: The main difference is this: In 2. The office IS **in** (within/inside)  London. 1 and 3: The office is NOT in London.

Comment: 2. The company's office is in north London.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the north of X and north of X means that it lies *beyond* X on its northern side (or "above" X on a map oriented with North up).  Some would infer that something which is "to the north of X" is not very distant from or relatively close to X, whereas a place "north of X" could be quite far from X.

In the north of X means that it lies in the northern part of X.

Edinburgh is north of  Manchester.

Dundee is to the north of Edinburgh.

Durham is in the north of England.