# How to specify the location of a place by mentioning its neighbors?

Tags: sentence-construction

Based on the this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134362/to-the-north-of-london-north-of-london-or-in-north-of-london), I conclude that I can say

- Nebraska is to the north of Kansas.
- Oklahoma is to the south of Kansas.
- Colorado is to the west of Kansas.
- Missouri is to the east of Kansas.

Now, if I want to convey all of the sentences above by a single sentence, how should I phrase it? I want to create a concise sentence.

Based on that post, I think the prepositional phrases act as adverbs and therefore, I came up with this:

> Kansas is limited by Nebraska to the north, Oklahoma to the south, Colorado to the west, Missouri to the east.

Does it make any sense? If No, would you tell me how create the sentence?

Comment: "limited by" isn't the natural way of referring to a geographical locale. We'd say rather that "Kansas is *bordered on the north* by Nebraska".

Comment: bordered to the north by Nebraska.

Comment: *bordered to the north* is not unknown, but neither is it preferred over *bordered on the north*. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bordered+to+the+north+by%2Cbordered+on+the+north+by&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbordered%20to%20the%20north%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbordered%20on%20the%20north%20by%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Doesn't _border_ sound much more natural in the active voice, somehow? "_On the East, Kansas **borders on** Missouri..."_ &c.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Do you use that verb when describing an area surrounded by other areas? For example, can I say the city is bored on the south by the mountains and on the north by see? Or I should use another verb.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: the passive sounds quite natural to me in this context, where the subject is surrounded by the other states.

Comment: @Cardinal: indeed we can. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bordered%20by%20mountains%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: I am not an ngram groupie by any means, but _bounded by_ is favored in both BrE and AmE by a **[small margin](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+bordered+by%2Cis+bounded+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20bordered%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20bounded%20by%3B%2Cc0)**. However, _bordered_ seems to be the more frequent usage in cartography as we advance in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you're looking for is **bordered**

> Kansas is bordered by Nebraska on the north, Oklahoma on the south, Colorado on the west and Missouri on the east.

Answer (score 1):

The noun *boundary* comes from the verb *to bound*, and the relationship you want to express is often rendered by using that verb:

> Kansas is *bounded* on the North by Nebraska, on the South by Oklahoma, and on the East and West by Missouri and Colorado, respectively.